# SQL Server dates stored as "Fri Aug 19 2016 01:00:00 GMT-0400"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inherited some tables and some of the supposed date columns have this type of value `Fri Aug 19 2016 01:00:00 GMT-0400` in them. How could I convert it to just `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` in my query?

I tried a lot of things and it keeps complaining

> Cannot convert from string to datetime format

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your "supposed date" fields sound like strings, rather than dates.  Not using the right types is the root cause of this type of problem.

Comment: I think you need to write a function which holds the conversion logic (assuming you want to SQL the conversion process to a datetime field)

Comment: are you wanting to stick with local time, or do you need to go to Universal Time?  (GMT + 00:00) and/or are you going to keep or drop the time zone info?

Comment: Gordon, it is a text field :(
Cato - I'd like to stick to local time

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your columns are not datetimes but strings. It would be better to convert those columns to the datetime type. But you can achieve what your looking for with something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(mydatecolumn,5,20)), 101) 
       + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(mydatecolumn,5,20)), 8)
```

Comment: But those strings are not able to be directly convert to a datetime. You have to strip a bunch of stuff out first. Ugh.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct I added a substring to them to pull out the part of the string that can be converted. It is ripping off the GMT conversion. Do you need that as well?

Comment: I am getting the same error message using all of the methods everyone has posted ;(.

Answer (score 0):

Below query works in SQL Server 2012 and not considering UTC value

```
DECLARE @Input varchar(32), @Output VARCHAR(32)
SELECT @Input = 'Fri Aug 19 2016 1:00:00 GMT-400'
SELECT @Output = FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(@Input, 1, 4, ''), PATINDEX('%[^0-9 :]%', LTRIM(SUBSTRING(STUFF(@Input, 1, 4, ''), PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%', STUFF(@Input, 1, 4, '')), LEN(STUFF(@Input, 1, 4, ''))))) + PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%', STUFF(@Input, 1, 4, '')), LEN(STUFF(@Input, 1, 4, '')), '')), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
SELECT @Output
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Date string values have  the same exact format (ie ddd mmm dd yyyy hh:nn:ss) then the following should work:

```
DECLARE @Dt NVARCHAR(50) = 'Fri Aug 19 2016 01:00:00 GMT-0400'

SELECT
    CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SUBSTRING(@Dt, CHARINDEX(' ', @Dt) + 1, LEN(@Dt)), 120) AS DATETIME)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93002/2)